# django Product delete

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to delete Prodcut specific id. After pressing YES nothing happened.

```
def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)  #also did try obj = Product.objects.get(id=id).delete()
# also did try obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if request.method == 'Post':
        obj.delete()
    context = { 'object': obj }
    return render(request, 'products/products_delete.html', context)
```

urls:

```
path('del/<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='product_delete'),
```

```
template:
<form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Do you want to delete the prodcut "{{ object.title }}"?</h1> 
    
    <p><input type='submit' value='YES' /> <a href = '../'>Cancel</a></p>
</form>
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/del/2/delete/

Screen:

Do you want to delete the product "second product"?
YES Cancel

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method is always written in *all caps*, so `'POST'`, `'GET'`, etc.:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj.delete()
    context = { 'object': obj }
    return render(request, 'products/products_delete.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simply solution to your question

```
enter code heredef product_delete_view(request, id):
# if request.method == 'POST':
obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
obj.delete()
context = {
    'object': obj
}
return render(request, ''products/products_delete.html'', context)
```

I commented the 'if' condition because it is giving me an 'unbound error', but I assure you the codes work as expected. The problem was that 'obj.delete()' was also an 'unbound error', so to avoid that I defined them next to each other so that 'obj.delete()' would be a direct reference to 'obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)'. I might have the wrong terminologies here, as I am a beginner in Django, but I hope the explanation was understood?